# passing ref from parent functional component to child class component to call a function in child class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-ref, create-ref

I have a parent functonal component:

```
const parentFunc = () => {
  if (ref.current) {
   ref.current.getKinList();
  }
 };

<TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => {parentFunc()}
>
  <Text>click</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<ChildComponent
  ref={ref}
/>
```

child class component:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.ref = { current: { function2 : this.function2 } };
 };

function2 = () => {
  console.log('called from child');
 };
```

function2 is not getting called from parent component.

There are solutions available, but I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

When I consoled `ref.current` in `parentFunc` it is coming as undefined

Comment: Based on the code you shared, it seems like you are not initializing ```ref``` correctly. Shouldn't you be using ```this.props.ref``` in place of ```this.ref = ...``` to make use of the ref object passed in from parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const actions = React.useRef({
    setMyAction: (f) => {
      actions.current.myAction = f;
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => actions.current.myAction()}>click</div>
      <ChildComponent actions={actions.current} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ChildComponent = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setMyAction(() => {
    console.log("called from child");
  });
  return null;
};
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-minsky-rg8u70?file=/src/App.js:51-480)

Also keep in mind that `ref` is a special name, not a usual property.

Comment: inside `parentFunc`, there are other functionalities too, where will those be integrated in your answer

Comment: @pratteekshaurya You can put `parentFunc` logic into an `actions` object or directly into `onClick` handler. It is not clear for me how `function2` and `getKinList` are related.